# FizzBuzzWoof in F#

Tags: f#, fizzbuzz

I'm learning F#, and have challenged myself to write a good functional implementation of FizzBuzzWoof. (The difference from "standard" FizzBuzz is that any number that either *is divisible by* or *contains* the appropriate number must be replaced by the appropriate string of text: 3 = Fizz, 5 = Buzz, 7 = Woof. Also, the strings must be printed in that order.)

I wrote a version using partial matching that I'm quite happy with, except for the one darn `mutable` Boolean in there that makes it feel less than functional to me. Is there a way I can get rid of that `mutable` Boolean, and still have clean code?

My attempt so far:

```
module FizzBuzzWoof =

    let isDivisibleBy a b = (a % b) = 0
    let contains a b = a.ToString().Contains(b.ToString())

    let fizzBuzzWoofMatcher n = fun i ->
        if isDivisibleBy i n then Some ()
        elif contains i n then Some ()
        else None

    let (|Fizz|_|) i = fizzBuzzWoofMatcher 3
    let (|Buzz|_|) i = fizzBuzzWoofMatcher 5
    let (|Woof|_|) i = fizzBuzzWoofMatcher 7


open FizzBuzzWoof

let runme () =
    for i = 1 to 100 do
        let mutable matched = false  // Want to eliminate this
        match i with
        | Fizz () -> printf "Fizz"; matched <- true
        | _ -> ()
        match i with
        | Buzz () -> printf "Buzz"; matched <- true
        | _ -> ()
        match i with
        | Woof () -> printf "Woof"; matched <- true
        | _ -> ()
        if matched
        then
            printfn ""
        else
            printfn "%d" i

runme()
```

I did come up with the idea of replacing the final `if matched` with another `match` expression as follows:

```
        match i with
        | Fizz () -> printfn ""
        | Buzz () -> printfn ""
        | Woof () -> printfn ""
        | _ -> printfn "%d" i
```

And this would work, but it runs the match functions an extra time. In this case this is absolutely fine since they're all quite fast, but what if I have a match function that takes a long time? Is there a way to run each match function just once, yet still avoid the use of `mutable`?

Comment: Not quite a code review as such but my own attempt at solving the problem in a more idiomatic way, maybe you'll find it helpful: [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexfoxgill/1ccdb406e15eb474191a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid using mutable by collecting all matching results and folding them into single bool value.

```
let matchSmth matchFun msg i = 
match matchFun i with
| Some i -> 
    printf msg
    true
| None -> false

let matchFizz = matchSmth (fizzBuzzWoofMatcher 3) "Fizz"
let matchBuzz = matchSmth (fizzBuzzWoofMatcher 5) "Buzz"
let matchWoof = matchSmth (fizzBuzzWoofMatcher 7) "Woof"

let runme() = 
    for i = 1 to 100 do
        let matched = [matchFizz i; matchBuzz i; matchWoof i] |> List.fold (||) false
        if matched then printfn ""
        else printfn "%d" i
```

Comment: And that's just `any?` then, right? (I'm not sure if F# has an `any?` function and whether it is called that, but many languages do.)

Comment: I have just applied `or` to all results. But `Any` function may be applied too. In this case `Any` is equal to `[...] |> List.exists id`.        
 (id is built-in function with  `'x -> 'x` signature)

Comment: I just happened to notice that, because I did a re-implementation of Ruby's collection protocols based on `fold` instead of `foreach` as an exercise, and the structure immediately caught my eye, since `any?` is then literally just "`fold` with `false` as initial value and `||]` as the folding operation". (Well, actually, `any?` is lazy in Ruby, so you have to somehow break out early as soon as you find a true value.)

Comment: Thanks; that's what I was looking for and failing to come up with myself. Also, I like the `matchSmth` function -- I didn't notice that I was duplicating code with those three identical `match` expressions, but I certainly was. So you've given me two ways to make my code more functional -- thank you.